# How to convert this Java code into Lambda and Stream implementation?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have an implementation to find duplicate characters in a `String`:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    Character ch = word.charAt(i);
    if (charMap.containsKey(ch)) {
        charMap.put(ch, charMap.get(ch) + 1);
    } else {
        charMap.put(ch, 1);
    }
}
```

I want to know if I can convert this implementation into an `Java 8` and `Stream` implementation. To do something like this:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then convert the `String` `word` into a `List` of characters:

```
List<Character> chars = word.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And now to do something like that:

```
chars.stream()
        .filter(e -> charMap.containsKey(e))...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
        Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
        String word = "acbczabcd";
        word.chars().forEach(ch -> charMap.put((char) ch, charMap.getOrDefault((char) ch, 0) + 1));
```

, with `mapToObj`

```
word.chars().mapToObj(n -> (char) n).forEach(ch -> charMap.put(ch, charMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. This is the result if I run your code: a : 3 
b : 3 
c : 4 
d : 2 
z : 2

Comment: yes, because in the post you start counting from 1. I have updated it :)

Comment: It gets now `{a=2, b=2, c=3, d=1, z=1}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need streams here. Just write a for loop. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<Character, Integer> chCntMap = new HashMap<>();
for (char ch : word.toCharArray())
    chCntMap.merge(ch, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if I can convert this implementation into an Java 8 and
>   Stream implementation.

```
word.chars()
    .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())); // Map<Character, Long>
```

or if you want the values as `Integer`:

```
word.chars()
    .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), summingInt(v -> 1))); // Map<Character, Integer>
```

or via `toMap`

```
word.chars()
    .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
    .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, Integer::sum)); // Map<Character, Integer>
```